# zombie.js lose session in callback

Tags: php, node.js, session, authentication, zombie.js

I'm trying to authenticate to a PHP app using [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org) (tried 2 symfony2 apps and same result). But the browser session is not the same in the callback. I think this why the authentication fail.

Here is my node.js code

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");

// Load the page from localhost
var browser = new Browser();
browser.site = "http://localhost:8000/";
browser.loadCSS = false;
browser.debug = true;

browser.visit("app.php")
    .then(function(){
        console.log(browser.cookies.dump());

        browser.visit("app.php")
            .then(function() {
                console.log(browser.cookies.dump());
            });
    });

browser.visit("app.php")
    .then(function(){
        console.log(browser.cookies.dump());
    });
```

And the results with a different phpssid in the callback

```
$ node test.js    Zombie: Opened window http://localhost:8000/app.php 
Zombie: Closed window http://localhost:8000/app.php 
Zombie: Opened window http://localhost:8000/app.php 
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/app.php => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/app.php => 200
Zombie: Loaded document http://localhost:8000/app.php
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/app.php/js/0b50c2c.js => 200
PHPSESSID=3qsqvtaseidgb5599803evt604; Domain=localhost; Path=/
[ true ]
Zombie: Closed window http://localhost:8000/app.php 
Zombie: Opened window http://localhost:8000/app.php 
PHPSESSID=3qsqvtaseidgb5599803evt604; Domain=localhost; Path=/
[ true ]
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/app.php => 200
Zombie: Loaded document http://localhost:8000/app.php
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/app.php/js/0b50c2c.js => 200
PHPSESSID=jg9h8e2orbmbfq0dr65ni8ucs7; Domain=localhost; Path=/
[ true ]
Zombie: Event loop is empty
```

Is it a bug of zombie.js ?

Answer (score 0):

This due to php 5.4 built-in server. 
I've upgraded up to php 5.5, works like a charm.

I've currently no link that describe this behaviour.